# Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 - Nextjs & React

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, netlify

I am coming across an error when attempting to deploy a website through Netlify:

Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2

Has anyone come across this or have any solution? I am relatively new to development and would really appreciate any advice or answers.

[Click to see error I am encountering.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4sIF.png)

Comment: How you will build the site locally using npm or yarn?

Comment: What build command do you have set up on Netlify?

Comment: npm is how I build it locally. npm run build is the command.

Answer (score 0):

I had noticed this in the failed deploy log on Netlify much time in my life

I always doing below steps and it will deploy is successfully

In local machine

1. Remove or package-lock.json or yarn. lock.
2. npm install
3. again deploy build on Netlify

Welcome to Stackoverflow

Comment: I have done this. But unfortunately had no luck. :(